# Suggestion to Nested for each loop in Java

Tags: java

I need to ask one basic question

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         int[] x = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
         int[] z = new int[]{11,22,33,44,55};
         for(int y:x){
            for(int t: z){
            System.out.println(t);
            break;
            }
       System.out.println(y);

     }
}
}
```

**Output : 11 1 11 2 11 3 11 4 11 5**

However , i want output like **11 1 22 2 33 3 44 4 55 5**

What should i do to make this output?

thanks for help

Actually my original code is like this

```
for(PropertyItems propertyItem:propertyItems){
            for(Address eachAddress: address){
            propertyItem.setAddress(eachAddress);
            eachAddress.setPropertyItems(propertyItem);
            break;
            }
            propertyItemsandAddressDAO.savePropertyItems(propertyItem);
        }
```

Both propertyItems and address are Set<> . I want ePropertyItem and eachAddress to get setted.

This is full code

@Transactional
public Set savePropertyItemsService(Set address,Set propertyItems, Set propertyType,Property property) {
    Set savedPropertyTypes= new LinkedHashSet();
    PropertyandPropertyTypeService.savePropertyService(propertyType, property);

```
for(PropertyItems propertyItem:propertyItems){
    for(Address eachAddress: address){
    propertyItem.setAddress(eachAddress);
    eachAddress.setPropertyItems(propertyItem);

    }
    propertyItemsandAddressDAO.savePropertyItems(propertyItem);
}
for(PropertyType eachPropertyType :propertyType){
    eachPropertyType.setPropertyItems(propertyItems);
    PropertyType savedPropertyType = propertyTypeandPropertyItemsDAO.savePropertyType(eachPropertyType);

    savedPropertyTypes.add(savedPropertyType);
}
return savedPropertyTypes;
```

}

Comment: Don't use two `foreach` loops in a row, use an `int i; i<x.length; i++` counter and read from two arrays of element `i`

Comment: Can you please paste the code for `PropertyItem` and `Address`?

Answer (score 1):

As @Unihedron says:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
     int[] x = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
     int[] z = new int[]{11,22,33,44,55};
     for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        System.out.print(z[i] + " " + x[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```

**Note:** As @lpratlong suggests, the above code only works if `x.length == z.length`. Please treat the code as an example only!

Comment: Note that 'z' has to have the same length (or more) as 'x'. Ielse you'll have an ArrayOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like practice using print(). There is a pattern in your output. There are five similar groups that increment by 1 each time (alternating bold to show the groupings):

**11 1** 22 2 **33 3** 44 4 **55 5**

With this knowledge, you can write a loop that goes from 1 to 5. Then print each group:

```
for (int i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.print(i);
    System.out.print(i);
    System.out.print(' ');
    System.out.print(i);
    System.out.print(' ');
}
```

Comment: That does not answer thé question about nested loops.